# Theorical Mpx/s value depending of processor speed and RAM

Tags: c#, c++, performance, math

My teacher wants me to evaluate the theorical value of Mpixel/second that a specific CPU and RAM can handle. We must compare that theorical value to the real value we get with two distinct C# and C++ projects while displaying any loaded video.

I actually have no idea of how to calculate this, I'm stuck there. Any one as an idea?

Comment: Obviously it is 42. Now let us know why do you think this evaluation of theoretical value is is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "is wrong"? I just have no clue of how to do it.

Comment: I'd expect "42 is wrong because XXXXXX", but if you think it is not wrong estimate - than you have your answer.

Comment: You're in luck, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721912/matlab-matrix-multiplication-speed

Comment: Thank you, it does help a lot. I might come back with the final answer in a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I finally got:

```cs
[DllImport("KERNEL32")]
public static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long lpPerformanceCount);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long lpFrequency);

private long frequency;
Window1.QueryPerformanceFrequency(out frequency);
```

Later in the code:

```cs
Window1.QueryPerformanceCounter(out stop); // 64bit
double tFrame = (double) (stop - start) / frequency;
```

Here it is for the practical value. Still looking for a theorical value to compare with.

Answer (score 2):

First, I am by no means an expert in this area.  What I believe your teacher is saying is that you should have some type of awareness to how fast a cpu is (100mhz)?  And you should have some knowledge of how fast RAM is.  If your teach has only listed those two things as qualifiers to determine the speed of Mpixel/second, then you should be able to calculate a maximum throughout put of reading data from ram by the cpu and sending that data to whatever video device that exists (which doesn't appear to be relevant).

I intentionally left out any actual equations, to allow you to solve it.